# as.Date year offset in R

Tags: r, as.date

I loaded data from a `csv` that contains dates in the format 25-DEC-2018. I loaded this `csv` as a `data.frame` using `read.csv`, which converted the `dates` to `Factors`. I want to convert them back to dates using the function `as.Date`.   I am using the command:

```
test1 <- as.Date(dateframe,format="%d-%b-%y")
```

However, the resulting value for test1 is 2020-12-25, which is 2 years greater than the `date.frame` value of 25-DEC-2018. Any ideas what could be causing this? Or is there an easier way to load the date data as a `Date` instead of a `Factor`?

Comment: You need `%Y` for a four digit year.

Comment: Or you use `anydate(...)` from the `anytime()` package which exists because all this is too tedious and error-prone.

Comment: And there are probably several dozen other duplicates we could have picked to close this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
test1 <- as.Date(as.character(dateframe),format="%d-%b-%Y")
```

Comment: Still wrong as it uses `%y` when it should use `%Y`.  Try `anytime::anydate()`; it also converts from `factor` for you if it has to.

Comment: Right, I did not notice that. Thanks for sharing the anytime package.